# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message when sending MessageEmbed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message at
> RequestHandler.execute

```
├── discord.js@12.5.3
├── dotenv@10.0.0
├── mssql@7.3.0
└── nodemon@2.0.15
```

Basically it send message on server channel, but after sending message it throw the error

```
const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle(result1.recordset[0].Title)
    .setURL('https://www.ebay.com/itm/' + result1.recordset[0].ebay_id)
    .setAuthor(_state, _img, 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription(output)
    .setThumbnail(result1.recordset[0].IMG)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Price [Ebay]', value: result1.recordset[0].Price, inline: true },
        { name: 'Price [Poshmark]', value: result1.recordset[0].POSHMARK_PRICE, inline: true },
        { name: 'Price [Mercari]', value: result1.recordset[0].Mercari_price, inline: true }
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Bot by programerAnel', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

msg.reply(exampleEmbed)
```

All 100 lines of code on git: [link](https://github.com/ProgramerAnel/discordBot/blob/main/bot.js)

Comment: Line [40](https://github.com/ProgramerAnel/discordBot/blob/main/bot.js#L40) may be the problem

Comment: @MrMythical dear god, why my focus entire time was on this [ Embeds | Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor) and this line of code `channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });` thanks mate seems like you were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your entire code, it seems that line [40](https://github.com/ProgramerAnel/discordBot/commit/2ef65d8d60baf14342f6633eafb76713db0f3d3b#diff-11c5110d191fc5150a06b8a9fe9aa65c5937bfd3c499b7b0a02f3284dd24605dR40) was the real problem. Whenever you are sending something, never do a variable on its own. It could be [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish). Make sure to add a label so you don't encounter this error, and it will be easy to debug

```js
msg.reply("relatedLabel: " + result1.recordset[0].id)
```

Comment: I don't want to be rude but if you know in one line what may be problem when deploying that bot with heroku `2021-11-22T19:20:03.638705+00:00 app[web.1]: Bot online !
2021-11-22T19:21:02.075726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-11-22T19:21:02.147057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-11-22T19:21:02.344596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2021-11-22T19:21:02.425209+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: I don't know anything about Heroku, you can ask a new question for that